# Cast to a property reference to a subclass in Entity framework (TPT)

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, table-per-type

I've got the following scheme: (not really the code, just to get the idea)

```
class Person;
class Employee : Person;

class Company
{
    public Person ContactPerson { ...}
    public EntityReference<ContactPerson> ContactPersonReference {....}
}
```

Employee type got it's own table in the database (Table-per-Type inheritance).

Lets say I've got a Company instance without the ContacePerson loaded.
How do I load the ContactPerson so it will load Employee fields as well (if needed)?

Is there a way to determine it on the select of all the companies as well?

Thanks

Comment: I want to know the same thing. When loading Companies, how do I eager load all Persons so that if the person is an Employee all Employee reference properties to other entities are also loaded? I am aware of how Include(...) work for concrete types that are not part of a hierarchy, but when eager loading references to a hiearchy I'm a bit stumped for the syntax, since Include("ContactPerson") won't load Employee-properties

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to check by the type of ContactPerson.

```
if (company.ContactPerson is Employee)
     Console.WriteLine("I'm an Employee");
else
     Console.WriteLine("I'm a Person");
```

So if the Employee Class had a additional property of BadgeNumber.  You could access that property by casting Person into Employee.

```
if (company.ContactPerson is Employee)
    Console.Writeline("My badge Number is ", ((Employee)company.ContactPerson).BadgeNumber);
```